# Delete/Remove a foreign key with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We have various tables in our system that have a foreign key referencing to an id from the same table. This was added via entity framework a while back using the following code in our configuration files:

```
this.HasRequired(e => e.Pay)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(wcc => e.PayId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Note some are defined with HasOptional rather than HasRequired.

Is there a way to remove these foreign keys? I've tried the following:

```
this.HasRequired(e => e.Pay)
    .WithMany();
```

but this does not generate any code when creating a new migration, then I tried to remove the entire code provided above, and again, it did not generate any code when creating a migration.

Is there a way to remove an existing foreign key from the specific table(s)? I still need the field but I don't want it to be a foreign key.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try with HasOptional instead of HasRequired. Is you keep HasRequired EF will generate a foreign key not nullable. If you make it optional the foreign key will be there but will allow null. If you want to cut the relation then remove the Pay property in your model(This implies a serius schema change so be carefull you don't introduce bugs) and the relation configuration

Comment: @AndroFont I'm not sure this is an option. The reason we need to change this, is that we recently found out that records in the table that contains the data to which the tables have a foreign key linked to, will delete records which may have already been used elsewhere. In this case we want to leave the data in these tables but we will highlight this in a report which the user will use to correct. No ideal but no choice on the matter.